# Possible solution for Sipser 1.63

Tags: regular-language

Sipser's question 1.63:

> Let A be an infinite regular language. Prove that A can be split into two
> infinite disjoint regular subsets.

Is my solution correct?

> Since $A$ is infinite and regular, then the pumping lemma holds. We have a pumping length $p \geq 0$ for this language. We take one word $w$ in $A$ such that $|w| \geq p$, and according to the pumping lemma we split it into $w = xyz$ as in the lemma.
>
> We then define the two languages like this:
>
> $A_1$ contains all the strings $xy^{2i}z, i\geq 0$
>
> $A_2$ contains all the strings $xy^{2i + 1}z, i \geq 0$
>
> That means that $A_1$ contains all the strings that go an even number of times in that cycle, and $A_2$ all the strings that go an odd number of times in that cycle.
>
> We note that we have also covered the words that are not related to the word we split, since $0$ is even.

Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not correct, you took *one* $w$, how do you know $A_1 \cup A_2=L$?

How ever, your idea is pretty close,here is a solution:

> Consider $A_1=\{xy^{2k}z\}$ and $A_2=L-A_1$, Clearly $A_1$ is infinite, also $A_2$ is infinite because $\{xy^{2k+1}z\}\subseteq A_2$.

Comment: because $xy^nz, n\geq 0$are all in L, and the ones that are not related to it are also in $A_1$ because $0$ is even and $xz$ are all in $L$.

Comment: Suppose $L=a^*$, $w=aaaaaaaa$,$x=a$,$y=aaaa$,z=$aa$. Now $A_1 \cup A_2$ just gives $a^{4k+3}$.

Comment: @TheNotMe Suppose $L=a^*$, $w=aaaaaaaa$,$x=a$,$y=aaaa$,z=$aa$. Now $A_1 \cup A_2$ just gives $a^{4k+3}$.

Comment: I see.., thanks for the heads up

Comment: @TheNotMe However, your idea is pretty close, I updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: How do you define $A_1$ formally in your solution?

Comment: @TheNotMe Just the way you did in the problem statement, I take a long  enough $w$ and partition it like pumping lemma.

Comment: There is still the argument that $A_1$ and $A_2$ should be regular. If we prove that $A_1$ is regular then so is $A_2$ through complements and what not. But it will be tough for $A_1$

Comment: @TheNotMe We can write like this $A_1=x(yy)^*z$ so it is regular.

Comment: so what if we can write it $A_1 = x(yy)^{*}z$? What does that even mean? that is not a regular exp

Comment: @TheNotMe $x,y,z$ are strings, so it is a regular expression, and we have even occurrences of $y$ between $x$ and $z$ .

Comment: @TheNotMe $A_1$ contains all the strings that start with $x$,go an even number of times in that cycle, and end with $z$. $A_2$ is the complement of $A_1$.

Comment: $A_2$ is not the complement of $A_1$, the complement of $A_1$ has all other strings in $\Sigma^*$ that are not in $A_2$ too.

Comment: @TheNotMe You are right, I am talking about $A_1$ and $A_2$ in my solution. I meant $A_2$ is $A_1$'s complement with respect to $L$, or simply $L-A_1$